# Scheduling Software for meeting clients

Tags: scheduling

I'm starting my own business where I go out and meet with clients. I'm looking for a scheduling webapp/storefront with great UX where clients can make appointments and it automatically marks availability. Sort of like an airbnb page but just for me.

I'm looking for SaaS or open source software that I can run on my own server, either is fine with me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of companies use [Calendly](https://calendly.com/) to schedule interviews.  I found the user interface simple and it is capable of marking availability and suggested times.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case anyone else interested, you can try:

- [Easy!Appointments](https://easyappointments.org/): "a highly customizable web application that allows your customers to book appointments with you via the web." It is open source so can be self-hosted.
- [See here](https://edgeryders.eu/t/list-open-source-software-for-resource-scheduling-and-booking/6629) for a list of other apps to explore e.g. BookedScheduler

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will fit your need, but Google Calendar has a good [Appointment Schedule](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/10729749) feature

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).